# How do I clear all styles from a child element?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, parent-child

I'm working with a drop-down menu, but I'm having trouble removing certain styles from the sub-menu. The parent element has a `border-right: 1px`, but I don't want the child to have any border, and setting it to `border: 0px` doesn't do anything. Is there a way to clear all inherited styles from something?

**EDIT:** Ok, here's some code of what I've tried:

```css
parent {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
   }

parent child {
  border: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  }
```

At this point I think I'll just create a new ID to get around whatever's causing my code not to work.

**2nd Edit:** nope, creating an ID or Class didn't work either. This code REALLY wants that border . . .

**3rd Edit:** ok, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/som8wjtj/5/). For some reason the `list-style-type: none` isn't working on the fiddle, but it works in my own code . . . weird.

**4th Edit:** Ana pointed out the problem with the list-style-type, I overlooked it while copying the code. But the issue with the border is still there. I changed the color to red so it'd be easier to see.

**Final Edit:** Ana answered it! I was being a dum-dum and applying `border: 0px` to the UL instead of the IL where it belongs. Thanks Ana!

Comment: You need to show the markup as well as the css to get to the bottom of the issue. Have you used jsfiddle.net? It is a good way to share your code so people can help you.

Comment: right, the markup. Sorry. I don't quite understand the jsfiddle.net thing. How is it different from the code box this site uses? (will create jsfiddle)

Comment: JSFiddle allows you to edit the code on the fly and preview it exactly how it would render in the browser. It also gives you a distinct place to put your markup, css, and js. The code you have posted is not "runnable" since there is no markup and your classes aren't written correctly.

Comment: The border property doesn't get inherited as a rule and it doesn't get inherited in your example. Where do you see a border on the submenu? I don't see it, you only have borders on the list items - screenshot http://i.imgur.com/cSi8yiM.png As for the `list-style-type: none` not working, it does work for the one unordered list you set it on (`.nav-tabs`). It's not working for the submenu because you're not setting it on that.

Comment: If what you want is no border on the inner list items, then you're resetting the border in the wrong place - you're setting `border: 0` on `.sub-menu` when what would work is `.sub-menu li`. And btw, you don't have a border on it due to *inheritance*, you have it because you explicitly set it on all list items inside `.nav-tabs` (the `.nav-tabs li` rules). And you don't need to set it on all list items only to reset it on the inner ones - see the fiddle @sdcr has provided

Comment: @Ama - (smackhead) duh, that's why list-style wasn't working. Thanks. But I see a border even in the image you sent me. Maybe you can't see it since it's lightgrey? I'll change it to red so it's more obvious.

Comment: @Ana - Ignore the last comment, I didn't see your 2nd one when I wrote it. OHHHHHH! Yeah, that totally makes sense. I changed that on the fiddle and now it works. THANKS! I wish you'd posted an actual "answer" so I could click the green check for you, if that gives you any points (still kinda new to this website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add !important to the styles. So your new css will be border:0px !important;

Comment: While `!important` does serve a purpose, it is a bad idea to add it in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this to apply the css only to immediate children

```
#parent > li
```

If it gets inherited, try using !important to override the parent's css

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear the inherited styles you must override the rules by applying a more specific rule on the element of interest. Read up on "css specificity"

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


div.child {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: It may not be as simple as my "pseudo code" example, but your issue is related to a lack of understanding in that area (my opinion). If you want a specific solution you will need to post the code in a fiddle